# `history` command failed to store the previously entered command

Tags: command-line

Any command(which maybe right or wrong) entered in the terminal are stored in the `~/.bash_history` file and later these commands are displayed using `history` command.

But `history` command failed to store previously entered `sudo!!` and `^bad^good` commands.Instead of storing `sudo!!`,`^bad^good` commands,it stores it's functions.

For example,

```
sudo apt-gat update
^gat^get
```

After that,the output of `history` command as,

```
sudo apt-gat update
sudo apt-get update
history
```

What was the reason for this?

Comment: Can you get them via up down scroll keys?

Comment: why the history command doesn't store the sudo!! command?

Comment: What do you expect it to do in the example? I can't see another use case for another behaviour that I can think of...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the below example,

```
sudo apt-gat update
^gat^get
```

`^gat^get` is a shortcut to replace the `gat` in the previous command with `get` and then run the corrected command.

```
avinash@avinash-Lenovo-IdeaPad-Z500:~$ sudo apt-gat update
[sudo] password for avinash:    
sudo: apt-gat: command not found

avi@avi-Lenovo-IdeaPad-Z500:~$ ^gat^get
sudo apt-get update 
Ign http://mirror.sov.uk.goscomb.net saucy InRelease
Ign http://liveusb.info all InRelease
```

In the above second block of code you see the corrected command `sudo apt-get update` and then it runs.

So the `history` command displays the wrong command `sudo apt-gat update` then the corrected command `sudo apt-get update` as in the order.It won't displays `^gat^get` because it was an **shortcut**.